# Call to a member function addCustomerIdFilter() on a non-object

Tags: customer-attribute

I am stuck in a situation where I can't edit/create any new customers using the backend in magento.

The requirement was simple: **Create some customer attributes**, so I installed [this extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/manage-customer-attributes.html) to do the job.

It seems to add the attributes that I created using the customer attributes section from the backend but after that I can't access the customers section from the backend.
Everytime I try it gives me this error
`Fatal error: Call to a member function addCustomerIdFilter() on a non-object in xxxxx\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Customer\Edit\Tab\View\Accordion.php on line 74`

I tried everything including un-installing the extension but it doesn't help.
Please can anyone guide me how to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I solved it.

The problem arises if you have disabled the Wishlist functionality in your store.
It seems like Magento didn't implemented a check to find whether Wishlist is enabled or not in the file `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_View_Accordion`. So enabling the wishlist fixed the problem.

Although its a drag to keep the wishlist module active even though I don't need it.

Comment: Happy that it works! But magento team should have done a check whether Wishlist is active or not. If it helps you...
I wrapped the section inside an **IF** tag to check if wishlist is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Complementing the above answer, just add an override on a new or current module:
In the config.xml

```
    <global>
            <blocks>
                <adminhtml>
                    <rewrite>
<customer_edit_tab_view_accordion>Yournamespace_Customer_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_View_Accordion</customer_edit_tab_view_accordion>
                    </rewrite>
                </adminhtml>
            </blocks>
        </global>
```

And add a new class overriding the block with a little validation:

```
class Yournamespace_Customer_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_View_Accordion extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_View_Accordion
{
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $customer = Mage::registry('current_customer');

        $this->setId('customerViewAccordion');

        $this->addItem('lastOrders', array(
            'title'       => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Recent Orders'),
            'ajax'        => true,
            'content_url' => $this->getUrl('*/*/lastOrders', array('_current' => true)),
        ));

        // add shopping cart block of each website
        foreach (Mage::registry('current_customer')->getSharedWebsiteIds() as $websiteId) {
            $website = Mage::app()->getWebsite($websiteId);

            // count cart items
            $cartItemsCount = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
                ->setWebsite($website)->loadByCustomer($customer)
                ->getItemsCollection(false)
                ->addFieldToFilter('parent_item_id', array('null' => true))
                ->getSize();
            // prepare title for cart
            $title = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Shopping Cart - %d item(s)', $cartItemsCount);
            if (count($customer->getSharedWebsiteIds()) > 1) {
                $title = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Shopping Cart of %1$s - %2$d item(s)', $website->getName(), $cartItemsCount);
            }

            // add cart ajax accordion
            $this->addItem('shopingCart' . $websiteId, array(
                'title'   => $title,
                'ajax'    => true,
                'content_url' => $this->getUrl('*/*/viewCart', array('_current' => true, 'website_id' => $websiteId)),
            ));
        }

        // count wishlist items
        //THIS IS THE ADDED VALIDATION
        if (Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('wishlist')) {
            $wishlistCount = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->getCollection()
                ->addCustomerIdFilter($customer->getId())
                ->addStoreData()
                ->getSize();
            // add wishlist ajax accordion
            $this->addItem('wishlist', array(
                'title' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Wishlist - %d item(s)', $wishlistCount),
                'ajax'  => true,
                'content_url' => $this->getUrl('*/*/viewWishlist', array('_current' => true)),
            ));
        }

    }

}
```